# Excel hide row if there’s a value in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am look to have a entire row hidden if a value is entered into a certain column of that row “M”.

Example I have a list of items and column M is PO number, when the PO number is entered for that line item I would like the row to disappear(hidden). 
Goal is to only have items without a PO number to be in the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look into filters.

Comment: Sounds like there is a *lot* of info missing in your question. Please [edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1517222/edit) to rectify the situation

Comment: Updated it if that explains better.

Comment: This will need to be done with VBA and a [worksheet change event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change)

Answer (score -2):

Right-click on column "m" and then click Hide.

[image: Image Example]

Comment: This will hide the entire column, not just rows with a given value in them